# How to see untracked files in git instead of untracked directory

Tags: git, github, git-untracked

`git status` shows directory (e.g *smaller_fc*) is untracked. 
However, I want to see exactly which files inside the directories (e.g *smaller_fc*) are untracked.

I would like to know if .gitignore is indeed ignoring certain subdir inside *smaller_fc* dir.

Here is terminal output.

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
modified:   .gitignore
```

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
nets/models/500K_iterations/500K_iteration_eval.txt
nets/models/from_solverstate_150K/
nets/models/pretrained_model/
nets/models/smaller_fc/
```

.gitignore file:

```
.cproject
.project
.pydevproject
build
*~
*.pyc
*.caffemodel
*/solverstate/*
```

directory structure:

```
root
-models
--model1
---solverstate
----somefiles.txt
--model2
---solverstate
----anotherfiles.txt
.gitignore
```

Could not find it on google.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If git only shows that the directory is untracked, then every file in it (including files in subdirectories) is untracked.

---

If you have some ignored files in the directory, pass the `-u` flag when running `git status` (i.e., `git status -u`) to show the status of individual untracked files.

Comment: To permanently set this, run `git config --global status.showUntrackedFiles all`